# I've been reading calculus made easy by Silvanus Thompson and I'm puzzled about a step in the chapter discussing differential equation solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm self-studying calculus using Silvanus Thompson's book "Calculus Made Easy" updated by Martin Gardner. Keep in mind it's my first time studying the subject. I've reached *Chapter 21-Finding Solutions* where the author demonstrates some ways of solving differential equations and I'm stuck on this part:

Solve for $y$ in $ay +b\frac{dy}{dt}=g \sin{(2\pi nt)}$

First, divide by $b$

$\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{a}{b}y = \frac{g}{b}\sin{(2\pi nt)}$

Second, multiply both sides by $e^\frac{at}{b}$

$\frac{dy}{dt}e^\frac{at}{b}+\frac{a}{b}ye^\frac{at}{b} = \frac{g}{b}e^\frac{at}{b}\sin{(2\pi nt)}$

It's all clear until this point then the author say 
"*For if* 
$u=ye^\frac{at}{b}$, $\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}e^\frac{at}{b} + \frac{a}{b}ye^\frac{at}{b}$ 

*The equation thus becomes* 

$\frac{du}{dt}= \frac{g}{b}e^\frac{at}{b} \sin{(2 \pi nt)}$" 

and the author then integrates both sides.

My problem is with 
$u=ye^\frac{at}{b}$, $\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}e^\frac{at}{b} + \frac{a}{b}ye^\frac{at}{b}$ 

I have included the step the part after it so that the author's solution plan may become clearer.

My intuition tells me that if $u=ye^\frac{at}{b}$ since $\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{du}{dy} \frac{dy}{dt}$ and differentiation $u=ye^\frac{at}{b}$ yields $\frac{du}{dy} = e^\frac{at}{b}$ because it's a coefficient of $y$ in the equation, $\frac{du}{dt} = e^\frac{at}{b} \frac{dy}{dt}$ not $\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}e^\frac{at}{b} + \frac{a}{b}ye^\frac{at}{b}$

So where am I mistaken?

Comment: Your intuition is not right because $y$ is in general a function of $t$, and therefore the derivative of $u$ with respect to $y$ cannot be taken assuming $e^{\frac{at}{b}}$ as a constant.  (Suppose, for example, $y = t$; what would the derivative of $ye^{\frac{at}{b}}$ be, with respect to $t$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y$ is a function of $t$ and
$$u = ye^{\frac{at}{b}}$$
apply the Product Rule
$$(fg)' = f'g + fg'$$
with $f(t) = y(t)$ and $g(t) = e^{\frac{at}{b}}$
to obtain
$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dt}e^{\frac{at}{b}} + \frac{a}{b}ye^{\frac{at}{b}}$$

Comment: So my mistake was treating $t$ as a constant while differentiating